# Timezone object and SSJS

Tags: javascript, api, marketing-cloud

I am working on a fix for a User Initiated send created from SSJS. We create the email send definition and add the appropriate properties (CustomerKey, Name, IsMultipart, SendClassification, SendDefinitionList, Email and EmailSubject). The code then does and `InvokeCreate` with the email send definition. The email is then scheduled via a `EmailSendDefinition.Send(ScheduleTime)`.

Here is the code to schedule the send.

```
// Schedule the Send
var scheduleTime = new Date(eventDateTime);
scheduleTime.setHours(scheduleTime.getHours() - 3);
var oneHourSend = Send.Definition.Init(sendDefName);
oneHourSend.Send(scheduleTime);
```

All worked well until DST hit. We are now sending the one hour reminders 2 hours early. I am sure it has to do with the account default being CST.

I see there is a TimeZone object we can attach to the EmailSendDefinition. Is this how we set the BU on the account to send in “Eastern Time”? **If so, is there a document that will show what properties are required to be set on the TimeZone object and what properties are optional? Is there an easier or better way to do this?**

Comment: Be sure to mark this question as answered, or provide some feedback below to help get to the right answer.

Comment: Hi there - please return to your question and complete the process so the rest of the community know it's the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Found this doc on the object:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/timezone/

If that isn't working, you could always do a Retrieve on the SendDef to see what it is pulling back as example of how to set the TimeZone.

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/emailsenddefinition/

From the doc:

> Contains time zone information for an Account. For Create and Update
>   calls, this property defines the time zone for an Account object. On a
>   Retrieve call, TimeZone indicates which time zone is in effect for the
>   Account object in question. Without a specific time zone, the Account
>   defaults to Central Standard Time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does sound like you are having timezone issues. I'm unsure of how you would handle this off the top of my head, but always converting your timezone into 1 standard format then using code to adjust it to the current user's timezone in which is running your context is probably your test choice.

[TimeZone Class Doc](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_methods_system_timezone.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_methods_system_timezone.htm|SkinName=webhelp)

[DateTime Class Doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_methods_system_datetime.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_methods_system_datetime.htm|SkinName=webhelp)